# Spark Java: How can we access the p Values in UnivariateFeatureSelector

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark-mllib, anova, p-value

I am using Spark 3.1.3 and I am trying to take the pValues from the result dataframe of UnivariateFeatureSelector.

```
UnivariateFeatureSelector selector = new UnivariateFeatureSelector()
            .setFeatureType("continuous")
            .setLabelType("categorical")
            .setSelectionMode("fdr")
            .setSelectionThreshold(0.25)
            .setFeaturesCol("inten")
            .setLabelCol("group")
            .setOutputCol("selfeat");

UnivariateFeatureSelectorModel ufsmodel = selector.fit(expaftervector);
Dataset<Row> result = ufsmodel.transform(expaftervector);
```

I checked the methods it offers but I can only get the indices of the selected features.

```
System.out.println("Selected Features");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ufsmodel.selectedFeatures()));
```

Is there any way I can get the pValues of the selected features?